# Laravel - Pass more than one variable to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I have this site and one of its pages creates a simple list of people from the database. I need to add one specific person to a variable I can access.

How do I modify the `return $view->with('persons', $persons);` line to also pass the $ms variable to the view?

```
    function view($view)
    {
        $ms = Person::where('name', 'Foo Bar');

        $persons = Person::order_by('list_order', 'ASC')->get();

        return $view->with('persons', $persons);
    }
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Just pass it as an array:

```
$data = [
    'name'  => 'Raphael',
    'age'   => 22,
    'email' => 'r.mobis@rmobis.com'
];

return View::make('user')->with($data);
```

Or chain them, like @Antonio mentioned.

Comment: The recommended way is to use **compact** method to pass variables. That feels rather more elegant.

Comment: I think part of the choice would be based on the data.  For a simple variable this works but with nested data with in a variable compact or with would work best for manipulating in the view.

Answer (score 109):

This is how you do it:

```
function view($view)
{
    $ms = Person::where('name', '=', 'Foo Bar')->first();

    $persons = Person::order_by('list_order', 'ASC')->get();

    return $view->with('persons', $persons)->with('ms', $ms);
}
```

You can also use [compact()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php):

```
function view($view)
{
    $ms = Person::where('name', '=', 'Foo Bar')->first();

    $persons = Person::order_by('list_order', 'ASC')->get();

    return $view->with(compact('persons', 'ms'));
}
```

Or do it in one line:

```
function view($view)
{
    return $view
            ->with('ms', Person::where('name', '=', 'Foo Bar')->first())
            ->with('persons', Person::order_by('list_order', 'ASC')->get());
}
```

Or even send it as an array:

```
function view($view)
{
    $ms = Person::where('name', '=', 'Foo Bar')->first();

    $persons = Person::order_by('list_order', 'ASC')->get();

    return $view->with('data', ['ms' => $ms, 'persons' => $persons]));
}
```

But, in this case, you would have to access them this way:

```
{{ $data['ms'] }}
```

Comment: Yep, I got this far in the mean time. But now when I try access it in the view e.g. `{{ $ms->name }}` I get `Undefined property: Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Query::$name` What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the `->first()` on the first line of your method.

Comment: pjmil116 just edited to add the `->first()` Raphael was commenting about.

Comment: Ah yep got it. I just realised this project is laravel 3 and thus a huge source of my frustration. Had to change the query syntax to `$ms = DB::first('select * from people where name = "Foo Bar"');`

Comment: Laravel 4 and 3 syntax, for common things like this, are pretty much the same. You can still use `Person::where('name', '=', 'Foo Bar')->first()`. Edited.

Comment: How i can access this data in *view*? please guide me

Answer (score 34):

> Use compact

```
function view($view)
{
    $ms = Person::where('name', '=', 'Foo Bar')->first();

    $persons = Person::order_by('list_order', 'ASC')->get();
    return View::make('users', compact('ms','persons'));
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Passing multiple variables to a Laravel view

```
//Passing variable to view using compact method    
$var1=value1;
$var2=value2;
$var3=value3;
return view('viewName', compact('var1','var2','var3'));

//Passing variable to view using with Method
return view('viewName')->with(['var1'=>value1,'var2'=>value2,'var3'=>'value3']);

//Passing variable to view using Associative Array
return view('viewName', ['var1'=>value1,'var2'=>value2,'var3'=>value3]);
```

Read here about [Passing Data to Views in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#passing-data-to-views)

Answer (score 5):

This Answer seems to be

**bit helpful** while **declaring the large numbe of variable** in the function

Laravel 5.7.*

For Example

```
public function index()
{
    $activePost = Post::where('status','=','active')->get()->count();

    $inActivePost = Post::where('status','=','inactive')->get()->count();

    $yesterdayPostActive = Post::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->addDay(-1))->get()->count();

    $todayPostActive = Post::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->addDay(0))->get()->count();

    return view('dashboard.index')->with('activePost',$activePost)->with('inActivePost',$inActivePost )->with('yesterdayPostActive',$yesterdayPostActive )->with('todayPostActive',$todayPostActive );
}
```

When you see the last line of the returns it not looking good

> When You Project is Getting Larger its not good

**So**

```
public function index()
    {
        $activePost = Post::where('status','=','active')->get()->count();

        $inActivePost = Post::where('status','=','inactive')->get()->count();

        $yesterdayPostActive = Post::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->addDay(-1))->get()->count();

        $todayPostActive = Post::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->addDay(0))->get()->count();

        $viewShareVars = ['activePost','inActivePost','yesterdayPostActive','todayPostActive'];

        return view('dashboard.index',compact($viewShareVars));
    }
```

**As You see all the variables as declared as array of `$viewShareVars` and Accessed in View**

> But My Function Becomes very Larger so i have decided to make the line
>   **as very simple**

```
public function index()
    {
        $activePost = Post::where('status','=','active')->get()->count();

        $inActivePost = Post::where('status','=','inactive')->get()->count();

        $yesterdayPostActive = Post::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->addDay(-1))->get()->count();

        $todayPostActive = Post::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->addDay(0))->get()->count();

        $viewShareVars = array_keys(get_defined_vars());

        return view('dashboard.index',compact($viewShareVars));
    }
```

the native php function `get_defined_vars()` **get all the defined variables** from the function

and `array_keys` **will grab the variable names**

so in your view you can access all the declared variable inside the function

as `{{$todayPostActive}}`

Comment: You save my day, thanks!
I think this a great solution.

Answer (score 4):

Came across a similar problem, but if you do not necessarily want to return a view with view file, you can do this:

```
return $view->with(compact('myVar1', 'myVar2', ..... , 'myLastVar'));
```

Answer (score 4):

**`with` function and *`single`* parameters:**

```
    $ms = Person::where('name', 'Foo Bar');
    $persons = Person::order_by('list_order', 'ASC')->get();
    return $view->with(compact('ms', 'persons'));
```

**`with` function and *`array`* parameter:**

```
    $ms = Person::where('name', 'Foo Bar');
    $persons = Person::order_by('list_order', 'ASC')->get();
    $array = ['ms' => $ms, 'persons' => $persons];
    return $view->with($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this,

```
$ms = Person::where('name', 'Foo Bar')->first();
$persons = Person::order_by('list_order', 'ASC')->get();
return View::make('viewname')->with(compact('persons','ms'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $oblast = Oblast::all();
    $category = Category::where('slug', $catName)->first();
    $availableProjects = $category->availableProjects;
    return view('pages.business-area')->with(array('category'=>$category, 'availableProjects'=>$availableProjects, 'oblast'=>$oblast));
```

Answer (score 0):

For passing multiple array data from controller to view, try it. It is working. In this example, I am passing subject details from a table and subject details contain category id, the details like name if category id is fetched from another table category.

```
$category = Category::all();
$category = Category::pluck('name', 'id');
$item = Subject::find($id);
return View::make('subject.edit')->with(array('item'=>$item, 'category'=>$category));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
If your using laravel, try this:

return view('app-student.app-student dashboard',compact('education_level_data','student_data',.......n));
where by:
1. education_level_data----first-parameter
2. student_data ----second parameter
NB: And you can pass more parameters as much as you can.
```

Answer (score -4):

Its simple :)

```
<link rel="icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico')}}" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: This one seems a bit out of place in comparison to other answers.