# Adding Multiple Variables to a View in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

```php
$header = DB::select("SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableOne'");
$secheader = DB::select("SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableTwo'");

$variables = DB::table('tableThird')->get();
$variables = json_decode(json_encode($variables, true));
$tbHeading = json_decode(json_encode($header, true)); //json object

return view('admin/crosstabdata', compact('secheader','tbHeading','variables'));
```

When I print all three variables to view (`crosstabdata.blade.php`) file, it said:

> secheader variable does not exist.

Comment: Put your view code here please. And I think it's better to change the `admin/crosstabdata` to `admin.crosstabdata` in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```php
$header = DB::select("SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableOne'");
$data['secheader'] = DB::select("SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableTwo'");

$variables = DB::table('tableThird')->get();
$data['variables'] = json_decode(json_encode($variables, true));
$data['tbHeading'] = json_decode(json_encode($header, true));

return view('admin/crosstabdata', $data);
```

Hope this approach helps out.

Comment: I need three variable to pass

Comment: From your code, which variables? I figured you’re sending secheader, variables and tbHeading

Comment: What does `dd($secheader)` return?

Comment: Undefined variable: secheader

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```php
return View::make('admin.crosstabdata')
           ->with(compact('secheader', 'tbHeading', 'variables'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. Maybe the problem is in the view.

As an alternative, you can pass varaibles to your views like this:

```php
$secheader = /** ... */;
$variables = /** ... */;
$tbHeading = /** ... */;

return view('admin.crosstabdata')
           ->with('secheader', $secheader)
           ->with('variables', $variables)
           ->with('tbHeading', $tbHeading);
```

Then in your view you can access them like `$secheader`, `$variables` & `$tbHeading`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an associative array to the `with()` method, so your return statement can look like this:

`return view('admin/crosstabdata')->with(['secheader' => $secheader, 'tbHeading' => $tbHeading, ...]);`

Answer (score -1):

i didn't try to pass three vatiables directly but here is a way to pass two variables

```
 return view('admin/crosstabdata', compact('secheader'))->with('tbHeading', $tbHeading);
```

also i saw this question in stack over flow i think it might help you its about making it as an array and passing it as one variable see here

[Laravel - Pass more than one variable to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110757/laravel-pass-more-than-one-variable-to-view)

Comment: I need multiple variable to pass into view.

Comment: will you can pass that variables throughmaking them as array and pass the array loop though it and loop each variable again and you get the resault see the link and you will understand